# Object not appear in Cycles rendering (color, depth, normal) due to an issue in its materials

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I have an object that gets rendered with no issues using Blender's internal rendering engine but the Cycles rendering shows a blank screen. As far as I can tell, I do not have any issues with the things mentioned [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up) regarding this issue. What I eventually found out was that there is something wrong with the materials. I wonder if anyone knows what's wrong with the materials that causes this issue?

You can download the .blend file I used from here:

[image]

Comment: The blend file you have uploaded is empty...

Comment: @lemon Yes, you can load the object into it

Comment: @lemon I should have selected layer 0 before uploading. So basically you should select layer 0 and then load the obj in it.

Comment: I don't get the point as your blend file setting is Cycles and the imported file is an obj... that won't fit... what are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: @lemon You mean loading an obj file to render it for Cycles does not fit? I just thought people would prefer the .blend and .obj files to be separate. I'm trying to update the .blend file.

Comment: @lemon I updated the .blend file. I have always been loading obj files with rendering engine selected as "Cycles". I never encountered any issues. Maybe that is because the materials of the obj files that I have are compatible with Cycles as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't see anything in Cycles or Blender Render.

I took a look at one of your materials. I think you're multiplying your color input by zero, so the final output shows up as zero. After I changed this, I started seeing something. (Bright pink since I don't have your textures)

[image]

[image: material preview]

[image: "fix"]

Comment: Very tricky!! Unfortunately none of these shapes are made by me and people who have made them have made lots of mistakes. I am slowly discovering those mistakes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just realized that the renderings of depth maps or Normal maps is blank. Any ideas on why that is the case? btw, I will choose your current answer as the correct answer later. Just waiting for other people to see if someone can come up with a solution for depth map and surface Normals

Comment: Do you have depth and normal maps to use? You can use an image texture node to load the file. Bump is similar. https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?317203-How-to-use-normal-maps-in-cycles

Comment: Yes I need to use depth maps and **surface** Normals, not bump maps.

Comment: For surface normals, I don't think you need to set a node for it. What are you using for your depth map? What kind of material are you going for? Make make sense to start over since the existing set up is look for data that's not there.

Comment: ahaha hopefully! there's so many knobs to turn, sometimes I find it easier to start fresh than to hunt down settings.

Comment: I resolved the depth/Normal issue. I just needed to change the color from black to something very close to pure white. I had just changed it a little bit and it wouldn't work that way